# Does STL 'map' declared locally inside a function need to be cleared when the function exits?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

If STL `map` is declared locally inside a function, is it necessary to clear the map before the function exits? If not cleared, does it cause memory leak?

Comment: You did not tell us if the `map` object is created on stack or on heap. if one the heap, then just calling clear will not solve the memory leak problem.

Comment: @Jagannath "A map declared locally inside a function" means it is on the "stack". Unless it is static.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Like this ? `std::map<int, std::string>* m = new std::map<int, std::string>(); `

Comment: @Jagannath That isn't declaring a map. It is declaring a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Standard containers do not need to be cleared before destruction as resources are automatically released.

Note however that if your `std::map` or `std::vector` contains raw pointers to dynamically allocated memory then this memory must be taken care of.

In other words the destruction of a raw pointer doesn't deallocate the memory pointed to, therefore code like:

```
void foo() {
    std::map<std::string, int *> mymap;
    mymap["mykey"] = new int[100];
    ...
}
```

will not leak the key, but it will leak the dynamically allocated 100 integers.

If the map contains other containers then everything will be fine; for example:

```
void foo() {
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > mymap;
    mymap["mykey"].resize(100);
    ...
}
```

doesn't leak memory.

All this sums up to; always use containers or smart pointers; only use dynamically allocated objects pointed by raw pointers if you really really need to.

Comment: What an answer, Perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: @LinuxPenseur Note you asked about clearing a map. Calling delete on pointers held in a map is modifying the map's contents, not clearing the map. The map doesn't own the pointees, just the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

> Does STL 'map' declared locally inside a function need to be cleared when the function exits?

No, the destructors of standard library containers<sup>*</sup> take care of clearing up their own resources. Otherwise they would be quite unusable.

---

<sup>* The same applies to the STL, but I believe you are referring to the C++ standard library</sup>

Answer (score -1):

That depends on whether the STL map was created on heap or on stack in the function. 
If the STL map was created on heap it needs to be deleted. If the STL map is created on stack, the destructor for the map shall be called automatically during stack unwinding.

Also note that, if the STL container holds pointers, then the memory pointed by these pointers will have to be freed explicitly. Here, the destructor of STL will only free the memory allocated to hold the pointers; but not the memory pointed by the held pointers.

For STL containers holding copies (of objects or other basic data types), the destructor for these objects shall be called by the STL destructor before the STL itself is cleaned up during stack unwinding.